# How do I access a class's variables from a class that I created within that class?

Tags: java, class

I have two classes as such:

```
public class A{
    ArrayList<Runnable> classBList = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
    int x = 0;

    public A(){
        //This code here is in a loop so it gets called a variable number of times
        classBList.add(new B());
        new Thread(classBList.get(classBList.size())).start();
    }
}

public class B implements Runnable{
    public B(){

    }

    public void run(){
        //Does some things here. blah blah blah...
        x++;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to have the instance of class B change the variable x in class A, the class that created class B. However, I do not know how I would let class B know that it needs to change the value or if it can. Any suggestions on how to change it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The question is unclear. can you reframe your question?

Comment: Are you trying to count "tasks done" with x? You should consider synchronization ... see http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html section 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your `B` instance access to the `A` instance. There are a couple of ways to do that:

1. Make `B` derive from `A` and make the data fields (or accessors for them) `protected` in `A`. I would tend to shy away from this one.
2. Make `B` accept an `A` instance in its constructor.
3. Make `B` accept an instance of a class that implements some interface in its constructor, and have `A` implement that interface.

Which you choose is up to you. I've given them in roughly decreasing order of coupling, where the more loosely-coupled, the better (usually).

That third option in code:

```
public TheInterface {
    void changeState();
}

public class A implements TheInterface {
    ArrayList<Runnable> classBList = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
    int x = 0;

    public A(){
        //This code here is in a loop so it gets called a variable number of times
        classBList.add(new B(this)); // <=== Passing in `this` so `B` instance has access to it
        new Thread(classBList.get(classBList.size())).start();
    }

    // Implement the interface
    public void changeState() {
        // ...the state change here, for instance:
        x++;
    }
}

public class B implements Runnable{
    private TheInterface thing;

    public B(TheInterface theThing){
        thing = theThing;
    }

    public void run(){
        // Change the thing's state
        thing.changeState();
    }
}
```

Now, both `A` and `B` are coupled to `TheInterface`, but only `A` is coupled to `B`; `B` is not coupled to `A`.

Comment: ... where "changeState" in the OP's case would do the x++.

Comment: @Fildor: Thanks, yes. I've edited to make that clearer (and to move `x` back into `A`!).

Comment: I'd like to add also, that x++ is not atomic. I suggest using `volatile` or `AtomicInteger` since above code is multithreaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend Class A within Class B, i.e.:

```
public class B extends A implements Runnable {
}
```

This sets Class B up as a subclass of Class A and allows it to access its variables.

Comment: Not necessarily. He could as well give B a reference to A and have A implement setter/getter for X.

Comment: True - I just thought this was the simplest solution (although not necessarily the best)

Answer (score 1):

You need do make the class `B` somehow know about which instance of class `A` created it.
It can have a reference to its creator for example:

```
public class B implements Runnable{
    private A creator;
    public B(A a){
        creator = a;
    }

    public void run(){
    //Does some things here. blah blah blah...
    x++;
    }
}
```

and then pass the creator when you construct it from the class `A`:

```
...
classBList.add(new B(this));
...
```